# How to use the removed function

Tags: r, function

I would like to use `prescindMeta` in package `tm`, but I cannot find the function in the lastest downloaded version of `tm`. Therefore I checked the older version of the package and find that this function has been removed.

My question is how could I use the already removed function in a certain package or combine the older package to the newest one?

Comment: You will have to download the source for the new package and copy/paste the function from the old package. You will have to take care of the documentation and make sure there are no clashes in the code. This can be trivial or not trivial endeavor. Or you could write the package maintainer. But perhaps there was a reason the function was removed.

Comment: They say to use `meta()` instead.

Comment: @F.Privé thanks and could you provide with the URL indicating that replacement?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik  thanks I would try to contact the maintenant to see what could be done.

Comment: @exteralvictor https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/news.html

Comment: @F.Privé thanks a lot, I downloaded an older package and managed to install that one though.